# getting login and register issue from some mobile

Tags: php, ajax

I have created the login and register page using ajax and php. Some user send me an email "we can not register". But i see they are already registered from database. Users are not redirected after registration. This problem is sometimes said that they had seen on the computer, but mobile in multiple times.

I wonder if there's a mistake I missed, would you check for me?

The Ajax Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var form = $('#registerform');
        var submit = $('#register');
        var firstname = $('#register_username'); 
        var fullnamereg = $("#reg_fullname"); 
        var regemail = $('#reg_email'); 
        var regpassword = $('#reg_password');   
        var validated = true;

        form.on('submit', function(e) {
            // prevent default action
            e.preventDefault(); 
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL+"register.php",
                data: form.serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){},
                success:function(data){ 
                    if($.trim(data) === 'ok'){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('.login_form').html("Registered!");   
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                window.location.href = siteurl;
                            }, 1000); 
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    $('#form_error').html('Error, intenta de nuevo.');      
                },              
            })  
        });  
    });
</script>
```

and PHP code Here:

```
if(isset($_POST["reusername"]) && isset($_POST["fullname"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["regemail"])){
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["reusername"]);
    $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, ucfirst(strtolower($_POST["fullname"])));
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, sha1(md5(trim($_POST["password"]))));
    $thisEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['regemail']); 
    $registerTime = time();
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // user ip
    $saveUser = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `users` 
            (email,username,fullname ,password,registered,ip) 
            VALUES
            ('$thisEmail','$firstname','$fullname','$password','$registerTime','$ip')") or die(mysqli_error($db));  
    if($saveUser){
        $getUserID = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user_id,username FROM users WHERE email = '$thisEmail' AND username = '$firstname'") or die(mysqli_error($db));
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($getUserID,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $uid=$row['user_id']; // Get User ID
        $dbunm = $row['username'];  // Get User Username
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $uid; // Session User ID 
        $hash = sha1($dbunm).$registerTime;  

        if($hash){
            setcookie($cookiename,$hash,time()+31556926 ,'/'); 
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `session` (userid, auth) VALUES ('$uid', '$hash')"); 
            echo 'ok';  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You might be open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the password_compat library to get the same functionality.

Comment: @Jaydipkharvad Please do not add HTML to the question.

Comment: You don't need to query the table right after the insert in order to find the user_id, instead use `mysqli_insert_id()`.

Comment: Don't generate your session hashes like that, they're way too guessable. Use `session_start()` to start a new session and `session_id()` to get its hash.

Comment: @AlexHowansky some user getting a problem from when they are trying to register because of your answered sections ?

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for your answer. I have check it but can you tell me some user getting a problem from when they are trying to register because of your answers ?

Answer (score 0):

If the insert fails because the user already exists, then the PHP code will return a 200 success status but it won't echo `ok`. So, your Javascript code will fall into the success block, but then skip the if statement. Thus, if a user tries to re-register, they will get no error message and no redirect. You could have the PHP code issue a explicit error status:

```
if($saveUser){
    ...
} else {
    http_response_code(500);
    exit;
}
```

Then, if a registration fails, the AJAX call will fall into the error block.

Comment: Yes, you are right @alex-howansky . I have already made this those user didn't get any error message they are successfully registered but no redirections. There is no `echo 'ok';` Also i have checking the user registered or not from database there is not have any problem. Sometimes redirect is not working because of the `echo 'ok';`does not appear. I think the problem is $hash but why and what is the solution ?

Comment: In general, this problem occurs on mobile devices.